# How will use this code multiple times in single post?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#flip").click(function(){
                    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css"> 
            #panel,#flip
            {
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                background-color:#e5eecc;
                border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            }
            #panel
            {
                padding:50px;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="flip">Hide/show</div>
        <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**** Basically my blog is quiz related one,i want to show 10 answers like hide/show method so this code will useful for that,but if i use this code using multiple div it won't work,so i need solution to this.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of ids as id of an element must be unique

```
<div class="flip">Hide/show</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rt37j/)

When you use an id selector, it will return the first element with the said id. That means `$("#flip")` will return only the first element with the id flip so the click handler will get registered only to the first element